# Ruby block works with { } but not with do...end

Tags: ruby

I was trying to implement a bubble sort method that takes a block and returns the array sorted in ascending order.
For some reason that I can't understand I get the right result when I use { } but I get the error 'no block given' when I use do...end.

Here's the code:

```
def bubble_sort_by(arr)
  return arr if arr.size == 1
  swapped = true

  while swapped
    swapped = false
    (0...arr.size - 1).each do |index|
      block_result = yield(arr[index], arr[index + 1])
      # binding.pry
      if block_result >= 1
        arr[index], arr[index + 1] = arr[index + 1], arr[index]
        swapped = true
        # binding.pry
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end

p bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","heys"]) do |left,right|
left.length - right.length 
end
#the code returns ["hi", "heys", "hello"] when the block is passed with { }
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: If the lone answer given is satisfactory (which seems to be the case in light of the comment you left) you should select it as the preferred answer (by clicking on the check mark beside the answer). As your reputation is more than 14 you can also upvote it if you wish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Precedence matters.**

`{}` has nearly the topmost precedence and is executed *before* function application (before `p()` call.)

`do end` OTOH has nearly the lowest precedence and is executed *after* function application (after `p()` call.)

Put parentheses to avoid ambiguity:

```
p(bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","heys"]) do |left,right|
  left.length - right.length 
end)
```

In your original example, the order of execution was as following:

```
p(bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","heys"])) do ... end
```

Basically, you have been calling `p` with a parameter *and* a block.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough answer! I tried it out and it worked as expected.